# Python interpreter in Qt c++ application - numpy MSVC debug

Tags: python, c++, numpy, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I'm developing a Qt application that embeds the python interpreter on windows.
I'm using MSVC 2015 as build tool and Python 3.6.4. When I installed Python on windows I installed also the debug version. After that I installed numpy by using pip command.

As test I'm trying to execute the simple python function (reported below) and everything works fine when I use the release build.

```
def testfunction():
    import sys
    print(sys.path)
    import numpy as np             #problematic row in debug
    y = np.float([1.1, 2.3, 3.1])  #problematic row in debug
    print(y)
    return
```

Instead, the program fails to execute the script when I build the C++ application in debug mode. I think that the problem is generated by numpy. If I remove that import numpy and the creation of the array, it executes without any problem.
Is there a way to build numpy with debug symbol with MSVC?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is somewhat old, but it might help someone else. I just went through this same problem.

You will have to build numpy from source in debug mode. Download the numpy sources from the latest release on their Github repo, extract them, and run:

```
python_d.exe setup.py build --debug install
```

This way you will have the debug version of numpy avaiable to your debug version of python, and the import will work. Note that the release version of python now won't be able to import numpy. I haven't been able to get both debug and release versions of numpy working at the same time.